# Observable not being filtered using .filter method

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I have the following code written using RxAndroid:

```
 Observable.from(check())
                .filter(new Func1<Response, Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public Boolean call(Response response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "******* " + response.getStatus());
                        return true;
                    }
                })

            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Response>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response response) {

                }
            })
            ;
```

The `Observable.filter()` method though is not being called for some reason.

Any hints on this?

Answer (score 0):

In the way your example is currently written it looks like you have a race condition. Your call to `subscribeOn` will cause your main thread to return while another thread executes your observable chain. When your main thread reaches the end of your program it will terminate (likely before any data is emitted from `check()`). You can add `.toBlocking()` to get access to block operators that will await a terminal event.

```java
int i = Observable.just(1)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .toBlocking()
    .single();
```

If this is not the problem (i.e. you are using a countdown latch or running in a server of some sort) then I would recommend checking that the iterable or future that is returned from `check()` is not empty.